# How can I set the proxy IP address and port number using the http_proxy package?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to connect my Flutter app's HTTP request with a proxy server, and I'm using the **http_proxy** package. However, I couldn't find any instructions on how to set up my own proxy IP address and port number using this package.

Example code:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  HttpProxy httpProxy = await HttpProxy.createHttpProxy();
  HttpOverrides.global=httpProxy;
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Package link: https://pub.dev/packages/http_proxy